# Visual Studio Nuget Package Manager Not Installing Anything

Tags: .net, json, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I tried upgrading Json yesterday but I don't know if something went wrong. Since then I can't update or install any package at all and this is getting too frustrating. I manually deleted Json from my references and deleted the dlls and jsol folder myself and still no effect. I tried reinstalling it. Even after deleting it from everywhere in the project, it says it already exists. I even tried downgrading it.

[image]

Any help?

**Update**

The following happened when I ran my project, this never happened before.

[image]

**Update 2**

When I try to uninstall it from here

[image]

> VS 2015 Professional .Net Framework 4.5.2 NuGet.Core 2.14.0

Comment: when you removed the json-package, did you also remove the assembly-reference in the project ?

Comment: @D.J. Yes I did, Idk what's going on..

Comment: what kind of project do you use (web-project, dotnet 4.5.?/.net core) /which version of VisualStudio and more importantly nuget package manager ?

Comment: @D.J.
VS 2015 Professional
.Net Framework 4.5.2
NuGet.Core 2.14.0

Comment: what about the nuget package manager ?

Comment: @Asbah Qadeer, What is the version of your NuGet package manager? If not the latest version, please update it first. Besides, you can try those methods, 1. restarted Visual Studio in Administrator mode, 2. Clean the nuget cache via command line in the Package Manage Console: nuget locals all -clear 3. Delete the package from packages.config, remove the the assembly-reference in the project file and delete the package from the Packages folder.